# java solaris studio performance analyzer - HW counters are temporarily unavailable

Tags: java, solaris-studio

I'm using java solaris studio performance analyzer mainly to get use of the hardware counters. But every time I try and use them I get this error:

```
HW counters are temporarily unavailable; they may be in use for system profiling
```

This is an example command line:

```
collect -h l2h/3,1 -j on java HelloWorld
```

Any help gratefully received